# How do I colour code my plot in R, based on peak and non-peak times?

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, ggplot2

. I first created my data frame, DF.

```
date <- c("2018-06-25", "2018-06-25", "2018-06-26", "2018-06-26", "2018-06-27", "2018-06-27")

time <- c("10:11:11","17:30:30","15:55:00","18:35:30", "09:06:01","20:15:30")

temperature <- c("15", "18", "16", "17", "14", "15")

DF <- data.frame(date, time, temperature)

DF$Date_Time <- paste(DF$date, DF$time)

DF$Date_Time <- ymd_hms(DF$Date_Time)
```

. I want to plot temperature over the different date-times.

. I want to colour the points of the plot based on peak and non-peak hours. 9am to 5pm are peak hours and any other time consists of non-peak hours in this case.

. I am not sure how to adapt my code below in order to colour code the points on the plot. Can someone advise me please?

```
ggplot(DF, aes(Date_Time, temperature))+geom_point() + ggtitle('Temperature plot')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help:

```
DF$time_test <- ifelse('09:00:00' < time & time< '17:00:00',1,0)


ggplot(DF, aes(Date_Time, temperature, color = time_test))+ geom_point()  + ggtitle('Temperature plot')
```

or using the `data.table` package

```
DF$time_test <- between(as.ITime(DF$Date_Time),as.ITime("09:00:00"),as.ITime("17:00:00"))

ggplot(DF, aes(Date_Time, temperature, color = time_test))+geom_point()  + ggtitle('Temperature plot')
```

you could change the colors using: `scale_color_manual`

Comment: Unfortuntely i get this error message with that code: "Error in "09:00:00" < time : comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types". I am not sure why

Comment: @Jed thanks for letting me know. I have added one more option to my answer above.